# How to index R objects within a for loop?

Tags: r, seurat

I'm trying to use a for loop to simplify the following code:

```
a1 <- CreateSeuratObject (raw.data = a1.data)
a2 <- CreateSeuratObject (raw.data = a2.data)
a3 <- ...
```

I've tried the following:

```
samples <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
samples.data <- c("a1.data", "a2.data", "a3.data")
for (i in samples) {
  for (j in samples.data) {
    i <- CreateSeuratObject(raw.data = j)    
  }
}
```

But it returns the following error:

```
Error in base::colSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

The CreateSeuratObject function essentially tries to read the samples.data vector instead of indexing the corresponding item in the vector. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is a bad idea. 1) You are rewriting `i` every time through the inner loop on `j`. 2) You are trying to create `n = length(samples)` objects in the global environment. Instead you should keep the objects in a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways of doing what you want. I suggest you **do not use the first** way.

```
samples <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
samples.data <- c("a1.data", "a2.data", "a3.data")

for (i in seq_along(samples)) {
    assign(samples[i], CreateSeuratObject(raw.data = samples.data[i]))
}

samples_list <- vector("list", length = length(samples))
for (i in seq_along(samples)) {
  samples_list[[i]] <- CreateSeuratObject(raw.data = samples.data[i]))
}
names(samples_list) <- samples

samples_list2 <- lapply(samples.data, CreateSeuratObject)
names(samples_list2) <- samples
```